# Read serial in separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

My system is the follow:
in a separate thread I need to read continuous data coming from serial port. 
Now, I can read the string quite nice but only when I'm moving the mouse over the form  (why?) ..
also the button Stop Reading dosn't work, so I'm sure that there is some problem in my thread calling or something like that ..
any idea? I cannot find my error.. 
thank's a lot ..

```
   #pragma once

namespace part1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::IO::Ports;
    using namespace System::Threading;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
            findPorts();
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  comboBox1;
    private: System::IO::Ports::SerialPort^  serialPort1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  comboBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar^  progressBar1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button5;
    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
            this->comboBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
            this->serialPort1 = (gcnew System::IO::Ports::SerialPort(this->components));
            this->comboBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->progressBar1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this->comboBox1->DropDownStyle = System::Windows::Forms::ComboBoxStyle::DropDownList;
            this->comboBox1->FormattingEnabled = true;
            this->comboBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(678, 46);
            this->comboBox1->Name = L"comboBox1";
            this->comboBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(121, 21);
            this->comboBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // serialPort1
            // 
            this->serialPort1->ReadTimeout = 500;
            this->serialPort1->WriteTimeout = 500;
            // 
            // comboBox2
            // 
            this->comboBox2->DropDownStyle = System::Windows::Forms::ComboBoxStyle::DropDownList;
            this->comboBox2->FormattingEnabled = true;
            this->comboBox2->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(2) {L"9600", L"115200"});
            this->comboBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(678, 86);
            this->comboBox2->Name = L"comboBox2";
            this->comboBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(121, 21);
            this->comboBox2->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(608, 49);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(58, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label1->Text = L"COM Ports";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(608, 93);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(58, 13);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 3;
            this->label2->Text = L"Baud Rate";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(678, 128);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(90, 55);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 4;
            this->button1->Text = L"Init Port";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(678, 189);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(90, 55);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 5;
            this->button2->Text = L"Close Port";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(192)), 
                static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)));
            this->textBox1->Enabled = false;
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(59, 80);
            this->textBox1->Multiline = true;
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->ReadOnly = true;
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(170, 39);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 6;
            this->textBox1->Text = L"Received Here";
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(192)), 
                static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)));
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(59, 190);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(170, 20);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 7;
            this->textBox2->Text = L"Enter Here";
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this->button3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(59, 135);
            this->button3->Name = L"button3";
            this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 40);
            this->button3->TabIndex = 8;
            this->button3->Text = L"Send";
            this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button3_Click);
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this->button4->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(162, 135);
            this->button4->Name = L"button4";
            this->button4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(81, 40);
            this->button4->TabIndex = 9;
            this->button4->Text = L"Read";
            this->button4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button4->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button4_Click);
            // 
            // progressBar1
            // 
            this->progressBar1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(59, 46);
            this->progressBar1->Name = L"progressBar1";
            this->progressBar1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 28);
            this->progressBar1->TabIndex = 10;
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(56, 19);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(70, 13);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 11;
            this->label3->Text = L"Port Status";
            // 
            // button5
            // 
            this->button5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(252, 99);
            this->button5->Name = L"button5";
            this->button5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 20);
            this->button5->TabIndex = 12;
            this->button5->Text = L"Stop Reading";
            this->button5->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button5->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button5_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Silver;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(932, 485);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->progressBar1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->comboBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->comboBox1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion


        // find available ports
    private: void findPorts(void)
             {
            // get port names
            array<Object^>^ objectArray = SerialPort::GetPortNames();
            // add string array to combobox
            this->comboBox1->Items->AddRange( objectArray );

             }
// init button
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                this->textBox1->Text=String::Empty;
                if(this->comboBox1->Text==String::Empty || this->comboBox2->Text==String::Empty)
                    this->textBox1->Text="Please Select Port Settings";
                else {
                    try{
                       // make sure port isn't open 
                    if(!this->serialPort1->IsOpen){
                        this->serialPort1->PortName=this->comboBox1->Text;
                     //this->textBox1->Text=this->comboBox1->Text;
                        this->serialPort1->BaudRate=Int32::Parse(this->comboBox2->Text);
                     //this->textBox1->Text=this->comboBox2->Text;
                        this->textBox2->Text="Enter Message Here";
                     //open serial port 
                        this->serialPort1->Open();
                        this->progressBar1->Value=100;
                    }
                    else
                        this->textBox2->Text="Port isn't openned";
                    }
                    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException^){
                        this->textBox2->Text="UnauthorizedAccess";
                    }
                 }

             }

// close button
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                //close serialPort
                 this->serialPort1->Close();
                 // update progress bar
                 this->progressBar1->Value=0;
                 // Enable read button
                 this->button4->Enabled = true;
                 // Enable the init button
                 this->button1->Enabled = true;


         }

         // send button
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

              // add sender name
                 String^ name = this->serialPort1->PortName;
                 // grab text and store in send buffer
                 //String^ message = this->textBox2->Text;
                 // write to serial
                 if(this->serialPort1->IsOpen)
                    //this->_serialPort->WriteLine(String::Format("<{0}>: {1}",name,message));
                    this->serialPort1->WriteLine("s");
                 else
                    this->textBox2->Text="Port Not Opened";
                 this->textBox2->Text="Abilitate to read";

         }

void UpdateButton() {
    while(this->textBox2->Text=="Abilitate to read"){
                     // check if port is ready for reading
                     if(this->serialPort1->IsOpen){
                             // Reset the text in the result label.
                             // this->textBox1->Text = String::Empty;

                            //this->textBox2->Text="Abilitate to read";
                              // this will read manually
                              try{
                                  this->textBox1->Text=this->serialPort1->ReadLine();
                                  }
                             catch(TimeoutException^){
                                    this->textBox1->Text="Timeout Exception";
                                 }
                             // Disable the init button
                             // the asynchronous operation is done.
                                this->button1->Enabled = false;
                                 }
                      else
                         // give error warning
                         this->textBox1->Text="Port Not Opened";
                     }
}


void ThreadMethod() {   
    this->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(this, &Form1::UpdateButton));



}

         //read button
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             Thread^ oThread = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart( this, &Form1::ThreadMethod ) );
            oThread->Start();


             /*while(this->textBox2->Text=="Abilitate to read"){
                     // check if port is ready for reading
                     if(this->serialPort1->IsOpen){
                             // Reset the text in the result label.
                             // this->textBox1->Text = String::Empty;

                            //this->textBox2->Text="Abilitate to read";
                              // this will read manually
                              try{
                                  this->textBox1->Text=this->serialPort1->ReadLine();
                                  }
                             catch(TimeoutException^){
                                    this->textBox1->Text="Timeout Exception";
                                 }
                             // Disable the init button
                             // the asynchronous operation is done.
                                this->button1->Enabled = false;
                                 }
                      else
                         // give error warning
                         this->textBox1->Text="Port Not Opened";
                     }*/
         }
private: System::Void button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             this->textBox2->Text="Stop Reading";
             this->button1->Enabled = true;
         }
};

}
```

I think the problem should be in the use of the method inside the thread like this:

```
    void ThreadMethod() {   


        while(this->textBox2->Text=="Abilitate to read"){
                     // check if port is ready for reading
                     if(this->serialPort1->IsOpen){
                             // Reset the text in the result label.
                             // this->textBox1->Text = String::Empty;

                            //this->textBox2->Text="Abilitate to read";
                              // this will read manually
                              try{
                                  this->textBox1->Text=this->serialPort1->ReadLine();
                                  }
                             catch(TimeoutException^){
                                    this->textBox1->Text="Timeout Exception";
                                 }
                             // Disable the init button
                             // the asynchronous operation is done.
                                this->button1->Enabled = false;
                                 }
                      else
                         // give error warning
                         this->textBox1->Text="Port Not Opened";
                     }

}

         //read button
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             Thread^ oThread = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart( this, &Form1::ThreadMethod ) );
            oThread->Start();

}
```

th debugger send me an exception: I cannot acces to textbox in from a different thread wich was created

Maybe instead of "this" I can refer to Form1 in the just created thread ..

Comment: StackOverflow is not: Please fix my bugs. You should try to elaborate on what you tried to fix, what you think the problem is and highlight some of the interesting source code instead of just copy and paste a bunch of code here.

Comment: maybe not the perfection but better after the editing ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution  :)
I used backgroundWorker utylities:

```
    #pragma once
#include <windows.h>
namespace test3 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::IO::Ports;


    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:

        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            findPorts();

                 // disable this text field

                 this->txtBoxGloveString->Enabled = false;
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::IO::Ports::SerialPort^  _serialPort;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnEnableRead;
    protected: 

    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  comboBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  comboBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnRead;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtBoxGloveString;




    private: System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar^  pBPortStatus;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnClosePort;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;

    private: Microsoft::VisualBasic::PowerPacks::ShapeContainer^  shapeContainer1;
    private: Microsoft::VisualBasic::PowerPacks::OvalShape^  ovalShape1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker^  backgroundWorker1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar^  progressBar2;

    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
            this->_serialPort = (gcnew System::IO::Ports::SerialPort(this->components));
            this->btnEnableRead = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->comboBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->comboBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
            this->btnRead = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->txtBoxGloveString = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->pBPortStatus = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar());
            this->btnClosePort = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->shapeContainer1 = (gcnew Microsoft::VisualBasic::PowerPacks::ShapeContainer());
            this->ovalShape1 = (gcnew Microsoft::VisualBasic::PowerPacks::OvalShape());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->backgroundWorker1 = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker());
            this->button5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->progressBar2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // _serialPort
            // 
            this->_serialPort->PortName = L"COM5";
            this->_serialPort->ReadTimeout = 500;
            this->_serialPort->WriteTimeout = 500;
            // 
            // btnEnableRead
            // 
            this->btnEnableRead->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->btnEnableRead->Location = System::Drawing::Point(36, 48);
            this->btnEnableRead->Name = L"btnEnableRead";
            this->btnEnableRead->Size = System::Drawing::Size(101, 62);
            this->btnEnableRead->TabIndex = 0;
            this->btnEnableRead->Text = L"Send";
            this->btnEnableRead->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnEnableRead->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnEnableRead_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(192)), 
                static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)));
            this->textBox1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->textBox1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::Desktop;
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(36, 10);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(261, 26);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->textBox1->Text = L"Enter Here";
            // 
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this->comboBox1->AllowDrop = true;
            this->comboBox1->DropDownStyle = System::Windows::Forms::ComboBoxStyle::DropDownList;
            this->comboBox1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->comboBox1->FormattingEnabled = true;
            this->comboBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(626, 12);
            this->comboBox1->Name = L"comboBox1";
            this->comboBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(102, 28);
            this->comboBox1->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(626, 98);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(101, 62);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 3;
            this->button2->Text = L"Init Port";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
            // 
            // comboBox2
            // 
            this->comboBox2->AllowDrop = true;
            this->comboBox2->DropDownStyle = System::Windows::Forms::ComboBoxStyle::DropDownList;
            this->comboBox2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->comboBox2->FormattingEnabled = true;
            this->comboBox2->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(3) {L"9600", L"38400", L"115200"});
            this->comboBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(626, 64);
            this->comboBox2->Name = L"comboBox2";
            this->comboBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(102, 28);
            this->comboBox2->TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // btnRead
            // 
            this->btnRead->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->btnRead->Location = System::Drawing::Point(36, 116);
            this->btnRead->Name = L"btnRead";
            this->btnRead->Size = System::Drawing::Size(101, 62);
            this->btnRead->TabIndex = 5;
            this->btnRead->Text = L"Read";
            this->btnRead->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnRead->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnRead_Click);
            // 
            // txtBoxGloveString
            // 
            this->txtBoxGloveString->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)), 
                static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(192)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)));
            this->txtBoxGloveString->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->txtBoxGloveString->Location = System::Drawing::Point(139, 121);
            this->txtBoxGloveString->Multiline = true;
            this->txtBoxGloveString->Name = L"txtBoxGloveString";
            this->txtBoxGloveString->Size = System::Drawing::Size(260, 26);
            this->txtBoxGloveString->TabIndex = 7;
            this->txtBoxGloveString->Text = L"Received Here";
            this->txtBoxGloveString->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::txtBoxGloveString_TextChanged);
            // 
            // pBPortStatus
            // 
            this->pBPortStatus->Location = System::Drawing::Point(463, 121);
            this->pBPortStatus->Name = L"pBPortStatus";
            this->pBPortStatus->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 32);
            this->pBPortStatus->TabIndex = 9;
            this->pBPortStatus->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::pBPortStatus_Click);
            // 
            // btnClosePort
            // 
            this->btnClosePort->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->btnClosePort->Location = System::Drawing::Point(626, 167);
            this->btnClosePort->Name = L"btnClosePort";
            this->btnClosePort->Size = System::Drawing::Size(101, 62);
            this->btnClosePort->TabIndex = 10;
            this->btnClosePort->Text = L"Close Port";
            this->btnClosePort->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnClosePort->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnClosePort_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(458, 98);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 11;
            this->label1->Text = L"Port Status";
            // 
            // shapeContainer1
            // 
            this->shapeContainer1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
            this->shapeContainer1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(0);
            this->shapeContainer1->Name = L"shapeContainer1";
            this->shapeContainer1->Shapes->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< Microsoft::VisualBasic::PowerPacks::Shape^  >(1) {this->ovalShape1});
            this->shapeContainer1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(761, 444);
            this->shapeContainer1->TabIndex = 12;
            this->shapeContainer1->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // ovalShape1
            // 
            this->ovalShape1->FillStyle = Microsoft::VisualBasic::PowerPacks::FillStyle::Sphere;
            this->ovalShape1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(576, 125);
            this->ovalShape1->Name = L"ovalShape1";
            this->ovalShape1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 23);
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(549, 20);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(72, 16);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 13;
            this->label2->Text = L"COM Ports";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(549, 72);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(72, 16);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 14;
            this->label3->Text = L"Baud Rate";
            // 
            // backgroundWorker1
            // 
            this->backgroundWorker1->WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            this->backgroundWorker1->WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            this->backgroundWorker1->DoWork += gcnew System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            this->backgroundWorker1->ProgressChanged += gcnew System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            this->backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerCompleted += gcnew System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
            // 
            // button5
            // 
            this->button5->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(36, 184);
            this->button5->Name = L"button5";
            this->button5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(101, 62);
            this->button5->TabIndex = 5;
            this->button5->Text = L"Cancel Reading";
            this->button5->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button5->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button5_Click);
            // 
            // progressBar2
            // 
            this->progressBar2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(139, 346);
            this->progressBar2->Name = L"progressBar2";
            this->progressBar2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(532, 47);
            this->progressBar2->TabIndex = 15;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Silver;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(761, 444);
            this->Controls->Add(this->progressBar2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnClosePort);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pBPortStatus);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtBoxGloveString);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnRead);
            this->Controls->Add(this->comboBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->comboBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnEnableRead);
            this->Controls->Add(this->shapeContainer1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Uart Gui v1.1";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }

#pragma endregion

    // find available ports
    private: void findPorts(void)
             {
            // get port names
            array<Object^>^ objectArray = SerialPort::GetPortNames();
            // add string array to combobox
            this->comboBox1->Items->AddRange( objectArray );

             }
    // Send button
    private: System::Void btnEnableRead_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 // add sender name
                 String^ name = this->_serialPort->PortName;
                 // grab text and store in send buffer
                 String^ message = "s";
                 // write to serial
                 if(this->_serialPort->IsOpen)
                    //this->_serialPort->WriteLine(String::Format("<{0}>: {1}",name,message));
                    this->_serialPort->WriteLine(message);
                 else
                    this->textBox1->Text="Port Not Opened";
             }
    // Init button------------------------------------
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 this->txtBoxGloveString->Text=String::Empty;
                if(this->comboBox1->Text==String::Empty || this->comboBox2->Text==String::Empty)
                    this->textBox1->Text="Please Select Port Settings";
                else {
                    try{
                       // make sure port isn't open 
                    if(!this->_serialPort->IsOpen){
                        this->_serialPort->PortName=this->comboBox1->Text;
                     //this->textBox1->Text=this->comboBox1->Text;
                        this->_serialPort->BaudRate=Int32::Parse(this->comboBox2->Text);
                     //this->textBox1->Text=this->comboBox2->Text;
                        this->textBox1->Text="Enter Message Here";
                     //open serial port 
                        this->_serialPort->Open();
                        this->pBPortStatus->Value=100;
                        this->ovalShape1->FillColor= Color::Green;
                    }
                    else
                        this->textBox1->Text="Port isn't openned";
                    }
                    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException^){
                        this->textBox1->Text="UnauthorizedAccess";
                    }
                 }



             }
    // Read button --------------------------------------
    //this will start the asyn for backgroundwork
    private: System::Void btnRead_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync(10);


      /* // check if port is ready for reading
          if(this->_serialPort->IsOpen){
              // Reset the text in the result label.
              this->textBox2->Text = String::Empty;

              // this will read manually
              try{
              this->textBox2->Text=this->_serialPort->ReadLine();
              }
              catch(TimeoutException^){
               this->textBox2->Text="Timeout Exception";
              }
              // Disable the init button
              // the asynchronous operation is done.
              this->button2->Enabled = false;

              this->ovalShape1->FillColor= Color::Green;
          }
          else
              // give error warning
             this->textBox2->Text="Port Not Opened";*/

    }
    // progress bar -------------------------------------------
    private: System::Void pBPortStatus_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {}

    // close port button
    private: System::Void btnClosePort_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 // add sender name
                 String^ name = this->_serialPort->PortName;
                 // grab text and store in send buffer
                 String^ message = "e";
                 // write to serial
                 if(this->_serialPort->IsOpen)
                    //this->_serialPort->WriteLine(String::Format("<{0}>: {1}",name,message));
                    this->_serialPort->WriteLine(message);
                 else
                    this->textBox1->Text="Port Not Opened";

                 //close serialPort
                 this->_serialPort->Close();
                 // update progress bar
                 this->pBPortStatus->Value=0;
                 // Enable read button
                 this->button2->Enabled = true;
                 // Enable the init button
                 this->btnRead->Enabled = true;
                 // ovalShape
                 this->ovalShape1->FillColor= Color::Red;
                 Application::Exit();       

         }
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }


private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {

             int count = (int)e->Argument;
             int sum = 0;
             String^ valuestr;
             while ( true ){
                 if (backgroundWorker1->CancellationPending){
                     e->Cancel=true;
                     break;
                 }
                 if(_serialPort->IsOpen){
                      try{
                            valuestr= _serialPort->ReadLine();
                         }
                     catch(TimeoutException^){
                            valuestr= "Error";
                         }
                 }
                 backgroundWorker1->ReportProgress(10,valuestr);
                 System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1);
             }
             e->Result=sum;
         }
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventArgs^  e) {

             txtBoxGloveString->Text=System::Convert::ToString(e->UserState);

         }
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs^  e) {
             progressBar2->Value=0;
             if(e->Cancelled){
                 MessageBox::Show("Stop reading glove by the user");
             }
             else{
                 MessageBox::Show("Result: " + e->Result);
             }
         }
private: System::Void button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             backgroundWorker1->CancelAsync();
             progressBar2->Value=0;

         }
private: System::Void txtBoxGloveString_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
};
}
```

Thank's to me!

Comment: Your question is sound,
people could share and you could learn the best practices for you particular case if you would allow it to happen.
But saying "Thank's to me!" doesn't seem to help much the others, you see?